# Не получается запустить чистый проект Vue ErrorStackParser.parse is not a function

Tags: vue.js, консоль

вот ошибка :

ERROR  TypeError: ErrorStackParser.parse is not a function
TypeError: ErrorStackParser.parse is not a function
at getOriginalErrorStack (C:\Users\Nefrittt\Desktop\test\node_modules@soda\friendly-errors-webpack-plugin\src\core\extractWebpackError.js:31:29)
at extractError (C:\Users\Nefrittt\Desktop\test\node_modules@soda\friendly-errors-webpack-plugin\src\core\extractWebpackError.js:22:20)
at Array.map ()
at processErrors (C:\Users\Nefrittt\Desktop\test\node_modules@soda\friendly-errors-webpack-plugin\src\core\transformErrors.js:31:17)
at FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin.displayErrors (C:\Users\Nefrittt\Desktop\test\node_modules@soda\friendly-errors-webpack-plugin\src\friendly-errors-plugin.js:97:29)
at doneFn (C:\Users\Nefrittt\Desktop\test\node_modules@soda\friendly-errors-webpack-plugin\src\friendly-errors-plugin.js:57:14)
at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\Nefrittt\Desktop\test\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :30:1)
at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (C:\Users\Nefrittt\Desktop\test\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
at Watching._done (C:\Users\Nefrittt\Desktop\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:287:28)
at C:\Users\Nefrittt\Desktop\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:209:21

подскажите в чем может проблема, появилась после переустановки Windows, node v16.15.1  npm v8.12.1

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло это решение:
https://github.com/stacktracejs/error-stack-parser/issues/80

используй error-stack-parser версией 2.0.6